TypeScript inconsistent error when assigning incompatible types
Can someone explain why I can't assign a variable of type MyInterface to Record<string, unknown> but I can do it when I replace MyInterface with an inline type annotation { myProp: string } of the same type?
interface MyInterface {
  myProp: string;
}

const myObject: MyInterface = { myProp: 'test' };
const myType: Record<string, unknown> = myObject;   // Error: Type 'MyInterface' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyInterface'.

const myObject2: { myProp: string } = { myProp: 'test' };
const myType2: Record<string, unknown> = myObject2; // Works

const myObject3 = { myProp: 'test' };
const myType3: Record<string, unknown> = myObject3; // Works

const myObject4: MyInterface = { myProp: 'test' };
const myType4: Record<string, any> = myObject4;     // Works

Stackblitz link
Sorry if this is obvious but I can't explain it myself and could also not come up with a good google search to find an explanation. Thank you!

It's not obvious unless you're intimately familiar with TS. Interfaces are not given implicit index signatures, as per ms/TS#15300. (Record<string, any> is an exception explicitly meant to be assignable everywhere. Also not obvious).
